# Sharing elasticsearch client in multiple expressjs routes

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I'm trying to reorganize my gigantic expressjs routes into smaller chunks by creating separate files. However, several need to connect to the elasticsearch client to perform searches:

**routes/index.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var models = require("../models");
var es = require('elasticsearch');
var es_client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200',
        log: 'trace'
});

router.get('/search', function(req, res) {
     // Do search in elasticsearch
     // es_client.search({......});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/user.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var models = require("../models");
var es = require('elasticsearch');
var es_client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200',
        log: 'trace'
});

router.get('/user/search', function(req, res) {
     // Do search in elasticsearch
     // es_client.search({......});
});

module.exports = router;
```

But this doesn't make sense since the routes are trying to connect to the es client twice, which will fail due to 'connection in use error'.

What is a good way to allow my routes files to connect to elasticsearch for searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a elastic.js file which is something like this:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
exports.es_client = new elasticsearch.Client({
                               host: 'localhost:9200',
                                log: 'trace'
});
```

and use this in your index.js and user.js.

For eg:- in user.js do this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var models = require("../models");
var elastic = require("./elastic");

router.get('/user/search', function(req, res) {
     // Do search in elasticsearch
     // elastic.es_client.search({......});
});
```